# Android - colorToHSV doesn't work

Tags: android, graphics, colors

I'm trying to use `Color.colorToHSV` function with this code:

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
android.graphics.Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
```

But the result in hsv array is always `{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}`, Whats worng? It is a bug?

Comment: What value is `color`?

Comment: All the colors return this result. But I need it to red color `0xFFFF0000`

Comment: Works fine for me.  What version of Android?  Which device?

Comment: I develop in SDK 4.2.2. and im using it in eclipse as xml attribute.

Comment: Try giving the color with no alpha value, i.e `0xFF0000` instead of `0xFFFF0000`.

Comment: The color variable made by the consts colors in the `Color` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when using colorToHSV in edit mode (View.isInEditMode()) the function returns zeros. When it run on device it works...

Comment: I am trying to use the colorToHSV function like this -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6407655/

but I am getting the NullPointerException at line 5. can you please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need to check your initialization of `hsv` array. It is probably whats wrong